# Google Sheet - Reference a folder that is inside the worksheet folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a beginner in creating Scripts in Google Sheets, so I would like some help to reference a folder that is inside the spreadsheet folder.

I would like to create a script that checks if there are more than 3 files in a given folder, if so, I would like it to return an error on the screen.

Important point: the files that need to be checked will always be in a folder that is inside the spreadsheet folder, so I would need to reference this, in the `CMD` it would be something like `.\FolderWithFiles`.

In this case, I cannot use the `ID` a of the folder which I want to be checked, because this is a model worksheet that will be duplicated several times.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to check the number of files in the folder including the active Spreadsheet you are using.
- When the number of files is more than 3, you want to show an error.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // This is your active Spreadsheet.
  const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
  if (parentFolder.hasNext()) {
    const files = parentFolder.next().getFiles();
    let count = 0;
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      const file = files.next();
      // console.log(file.getName()); // When you use this line, you can see the filename of the files.
      count++;
    }
    if (count >= 3) {
      throw new Error("Your expected error.");
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error("Spreadsheet has no parent folder.");
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the number of files in the folder including the active Spreadsheet is checked. When the number of files is more than 3, an error like `Your expected error.` occurs.
- If you want to use another Spreadsheet instead of the active Spreadsheet, please modify `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` to `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###spreadsheetId###");`.

#### Reference:

- [getParents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getparents)

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt For `more than 3 files`, I used `if (count >= 3) {`. If you wanted to use `if (count > 3) {`, please modify it. At that time, I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Excellent alternative! More important than resolving a specific situation is understanding the way to resolve it, and your patience and detail are exceptional, they will help me a lot in this evolution.

Taking the opportunity, I would like to know if it would be possible to count only the files that are inside the "FolderWithFiles" folder, and that have a specific word in the name, in which case I would have to look for a match of a specific word instead of matching the complete name. It is possible? Your English is great!

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand whether your question was resolved by my answer. Can I ask you about it? About your new question of `I would like to know if it would be possible to count only the files that are inside the "FolderWithFiles" folder, and that have a specific word in the name, in which case I would have to look for a match of a specific word instead of matching the complete name. It is possible?`, I think that it's yes.

Comment: It solved most of the problem, but I confess that I was breaking my head today trying to specify the folder that is inside the spreadsheet folder to search for the files, in this case I need only what is inside that folder to be taken into account. I still can't get it to work that way, could you help me please?

Anyway, your suggestion is excellent and solved most of the issue, so I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt Thank you for replying. I'm glad your question was resolved. About your new question of `in this case I need only what is inside that folder to be taken into account.`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By correctly understanding your new question, I would like to think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Of course, I'm sorry, I'll try to be as clear as possible

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt Thank you for replying. I think that the reason that I cannot understand your question is due to my poor English skill. I think that I have to apologize for it. But, I would like to support you. So, when I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: The question is the following: I have a worksheet, this worksheet is in a folder, inside that same folder that the worksheet is there is another folder. That is, in the worksheet folder there is it and one more folder, this folder is called `FolderWithFiles`. The `FolderWithFiles` is the one that has the files I need to be scanned. Anyway, I need this check to be done in a way that the folder `ID` is not written in the code, but it says that I want it to be checked in the `FolderWithFiles` folder that is inside the worksheet folder.

Comment: This is because this worksheet folder will be duplicated several times, since it is a model worksheet.

Comment: If you can't understand it, please let me know, I can elaborate another question and add pictures to make it more illustrative. As for his written English, he is excellent! I can understand it perfectly

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your new question. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. I think that when I could correctly understand your new question, I can think of a solution. I apologize that I cannot understand and resolve your various questions soon. I have to study more.

Comment: Sure, no problem! Tomorrow I will ask a new question and include pictures to make it easier to understand. Thank you very much for your attention and patience, it has helped me a lot.

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt Thank you for replying. When I saw your new question, I will check it.